# store value in .data as array and manipulate it

Tags: jquery

I have to store data in .data method as array and print them in span which is greater than 3.

I write the code but it is giving `'object object'`  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzSJf/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            var value = $('div').data('key',[]);
            var txt= $(this).text();
            $('div').data('key').push(txt)
            $('span').text(value)
        });
    });
</script>
```

// html

```
<div></div>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#">5</a>
<a href="#">6</a>
<a href="#">7</a>
<a href="#">8</a>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div').data('key', []); // init the array

$('a').click(function () {
    var value = $('div').data('key'); //pulls the current array value.
    var txt = $(this).text();
    value.push(txt); 
    $('span').text(value);
});
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzSJf/3/)

Comment: Because you're not explaining the error. You're "just" fixing it.

Comment: @OQJF Why? If you're not explaining whats wrong, half of the answer is missing. I don't know about you guys, but I'd feel like an idiot if I wouldn't even get a single sentence on what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting, every piece of contribution should be welcome, even it's not the best. If we always devote other guys contribution, the bad things will happen: no guys want to answer the question, because they don't know it can be accepted by the others. Commenting it with your suggestion can be better. And also sorry for my rude.

Comment: You're not being rude and I did not intend to be, either. I just consider incomplete things a potential cause of even more problems than the question was hoping to answer. If an error is not explained the chance comes up it is repeated, which costs even more time.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting, you should know what are downvotes for, and yes, you were rude and "not cool". The points and reputation are not important to me(I got enough as you probably see), the fact you give negative response to an answer helping a guy is sad, extremely sad (and rude), that is why I downvoted your answer as well(yep it was me BTW), when you act like an idiot it ruins SO. I would have revert my vote but it's locked by now.

Comment: @gdoron If you had edited it for completion I'd have been lucky to even vote it up, too. IMHO, which is abviously not accepted here, the lack of explanation makes people repeat their mistakes. How is that not a valid reason to signal you to add to your answer. I could have made a comment, but instead voted your answer down *and* commented. I was waiting for you to edit it so I could vote it up. I explained myself and my reasoning. You don't have to agree with me, but if you have to downvote me just for the sake of it, you shouldn't call *me* rude.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting, you should have only commented, and I would have add an explantion, but you just downvoted which is rude. anyway you're right that it's better to give more context to the answer, I'll edit it on Sunday as I'm in a hurry. Good day  sir.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this line.

```
var value=  $('div').data('key',[]);
```

You are assigning the return value of `.data()` to value, which, as with most other jQuery functions, returns the jQuery object itself. You later use that Object as text for the span. Thats where the error comes from. To fix this, first init the data attribute once outside the click and set `var value` separately inside the way gdoron does it.